# Get the values from GridView items

Tags: java, android, gridview, textview, parent-child

I am working on a project where I have a let's say 5x5 grid of TextViews and I want to check if an entire row or column has equal elements. I am using an Adapter class to inflate my gridview with simply one textview element. Here is the code that I have tried but I cannot seem to make it work:

```
 final int size = gridView.getCount(); //25
 int temp = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        ViewGroup gridChild = (ViewGroup) gridView.getChildAt(i);
        childSize = gridChild.getChildCount();

        for (int j = 0; j < childSize; j++) {

            if (gridChild.getChildAt(j) instanceof TextView &&
                    ((TextView) gridChild.getChildAt(j)).getText().toString().equals("x")) {
                temp++;
            }
```

The thing is when i tried to debug, debugger showed null values for childSize variable and could not properly get the value from getChildAt. Basically, what I am trying to do is get inside the if statement. Also this is the first time I am working with ViewGroup calss, and the methods that I call. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:I am looking for a way to do this outside the getView method in the adapter class and not in a onClick method as well. (Code sample answers would be highly appreciated). Also, the getChildAt method call returns null so the code I have shown would not work because I am assigning a null value to the gridChild.

This is the onClick that I use for the TextViews:

`

```
 public void numberFill(View view) {
        if (((TextView) view).getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
            ((TextView) view).setText(String.valueOf(numbCounter + 1));
            numbCounter++;
        }

        else if (!((TextView) view).getText().toString().isEmpty() && numbCounter >= 16) {
            ((TextView) view).setText("x");
        }
    }
```

This is my adapter class:

```
public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final Context mContext;
    private  String[] numbers;


    public GridAdapter(Context context, String[] numbers) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.numbers = numbers;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return numbers.length;
    }


    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }


    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return numbers[position];
        //return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
                mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View gridView;


        if (convertView == null) {

            gridView = new View(mContext);


            gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.textview_layout, null);


            TextView textView = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.cell);
            textView.setText(numbers[position]);

        } else {
            gridView = (View) convertView;
        }

        return gridView;
    }

}
```

numberFill reworked:

```
    public void numberFill(View view) {
    int index = (Integer) view.getTag();
    if (numbers[index].toString().isEmpty()) {
        numbers[index] = String.valueOf(numbCounter + 1);
        numbCounter++;
    }

    else if (!numbers[index].toString().isEmpty() && numbCounter >= 25) {
        numbers[index] = "x";
    }

    gridAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

`

Comment: `childSize` can't be null, at least not after the `childSize = gridChild.getChildCount();` line. `getChildCount()` returns a primitive `int`, which cannot be null. Also, why are you trying to iterate over each `GridView` child's children? If each item is simply a `TextView`, then they aren't going to have children. Aside from that, why don't you check the dataset backing the `Adapter` for the values, instead of doing it roundabout through the `View`s?

Comment: I agree with Mike that doing this work in the adapter will be a lot more easier. But if you need to do it outside, changing to a RecyclerView and using GridLayoutManager`s findViewById (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#findViewByPosition(int)) will be a lot easier

Comment: @MikeM. What do you mean by "check the dataset backing the Adapter for the values" :?

Comment: I'm referring to the data – presumably `String`s – that you're using to `setText()` on the `TextView`s. Often with `Adapter`s, those are in the form of an array or `List`. If you already have those `String`s, there's no need to try to get them from the `TextView`s.

Comment: @MikeM. I edited with the onClick if it helps anyhow.

Comment: @MikeM. I got a bit confused because I am reasearching for my problem from many sources and get different replies, if you could explain it with a sample I would be extremely pleased. :)

Comment: OK, so you're not storing those values anywhere else? How are you creating the `Adapter`?

Comment: @MikeM. I added the whole adapter class.

Comment: OK, there ya go. `String[] numbers` is the dataset I'm talking about. Normally, with an `AdapterView` – like your `GridView` here – the values are first updated in the dataset, then propagated to UI by refreshing the `AdapterView`, which is done by calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the `Adapter`. If you follow that procedure, then you wouldn't have to try to retrieve the values from all they different `TextView`s; they're already right there in your array.

Comment: @MikeM. So you are basically saying that I have to override the notifyDataSetChanged() method in the adapter class which would check the  numbers String array and this would work?

Comment: No, I'm saying, in the click method, first update the value in the `String` array, then just call `notifyDataSetChanged()` directly on the `Adapter`. Don't override it. It's as simple as that. But the next question will be, how do you know which index in the array to update, yeah? With your current setup, I would use the tag on `View` to attach the `position`, which corresponds to the array index. That is, in `getView()`, call `setTag(position)` on whichever `View` you set `android:onClick="numberFill"` in the layout. Then, in `numberFill()`, `int index = view.getTag();`. Follow me?

Comment: @MikeM. Okay I think I could do this, one thing I did not understand is how exactly do I update the value in the string array :?

Comment: In the click method, `numberFill()`, instead of getting and setting the text on the `TextView`, you're just getting and setting the value in the array. That is, after you've got the index – as mentioned, `int index = view.getTag();` – the equivalent of `((TextView) view).getText()` would be `numbers[index]`, assuming you named the array in the `Activity` the same thing. Then, the `setText()` equivalent would just be assigning back to that same array element – `numbers[index] = ???;`. Then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the `Adapter`. Got me?

Comment: @MikeM. I think I got you :D , I will try that and see what comes out, thank you so much by far :)

Comment: @MikeM. I have a trouble in creating the "int index = view.getTag();" because view is an object and it says the types are incompatible; And one more thing, where do I exactly call notifyDataSetChanged in the adapter, I assume it is in the getView method?

Comment: Ah, yeah. Just cast it to an `Integer` first: `int index = (Integer) view.getTag();`. No, you don't call that _in_ the `Adapter`. You call it _on_ the `Adapter` as the last thing in `numberFill()`, after updating the array; e.g., `gridAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`.

Comment: @MikeM. I cannot call the adapter object  in the numberFill method because it is initialized in onCreate, how do I do this? I mean can I initialize it in numberFill so I can call notifyDataSetChanged or?

Comment: Look at how `mContext` in `GridAdapter` is accessible everywhere in the class. Do that same thing with the `GridAdapter` variable in the `Activity`; declare it as a class field – i.e., outside of any method – and then instantiate it in `onCreate()`. That is, outside: `private GridAdapter gridAdapter;`. Inside `onCreate()`: `gridAdapter = new GridAdapter(...);`.

Comment: @MikeM. Okay so I have done everything you said, the app crashed but I found it where(i was casting the tag to the gridview instead of the textview) but now on clicking the numbers just wont show. I think it is because I deleted the setText calls and I am still confused could you look at the numberFill method, i updated it . I am sure its the first if statement but still cant decide how do I combine the numbers array with the index and the setText to the view :?

Comment: In the `Adapter`'s `getView()` method, move the `TextView textView = ...` and `textView.setText(...` lines to after the `else` block, right before the `return`.

Comment: @MikeM. What the ... lol this actually worked okay I am really thankful for your help dude wow, I think I can do it from now on. One thing - how did this moving down before the return fixed it, I mean i want to understand it why and also I move the setTag along with those two rows of code down there right?

Comment: Yep, that's correct. An `AdapterView` recycles `View`s, as it will only hold a few more than you can see on-screen at once, if the list is that big. The first several times `getView()` is called, `convertView` will be null, and you need to create the `View`. Later, when it's recycling, `convertView` will be a "used" instance from a previous position, so you don't need to create it. That's the reason for the `convertView == null`. However, in both cases, you need to set the data for the current position, and when you had the `TextView` stuff in the `if`, it wasn't happening during the recycles.

Comment: Yeah, I'd noticed that before, but it wasn't an issue with the way you were doing things originally, so I didn't mention it immediately, so as not to confuse things. Anyhoo, glad you got it working. Cheers!

Comment: @MikeM. Last thing, could you reply with something as an answer so I can tick it up :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using an `AdapterView` – such as your `GridView` – you generally don't want to directly access and manipulate its child `View`s outside of its `Adapter`. Instead, the dataset backing the `Adapter` should be updated, and the `GridView` then refreshed.

In your case, you presumably have a setup similar to this in your `Activity`:

```
private GridAdapter gridAdapter;
private String[] numbers;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    numbers = new String[25];
    gridAdapter = new GridAdapter(this, numbers);
}
```

Here, the `numbers` array is what you want to directly modify, rather than the text on the `GridView`'s child `TextView`s. That array is then easily iterated over to do your row and column value checks.

Since the array will be modified in the `Activity`, we need a way to pass the clicked `TextView`'s `position` in the `Adapter` to the `Activity`'s click method, as we'll need it to access the correct array element. For this, we can utilize the tag property available on all `View`'s, via the `setTag()` and `getTag()` methods. For example, in `GridAdapter`'s `getView()` method:

```
...
TextView textView = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.cell);
textView.setText(numbers[position]);
textView.setTag(position);
...
```

In the click method, the position can be easily retrieved with `getTag()`, and used as the index to get the clicked `TextView`'s text from the `numbers` array. You can then do the necessary processing or calculation with that text, set the modified value back to the array element, and trigger a refresh on the `Adapter`.

```
public void numberFill(View view) {
    int index = (Integer) view.getTag();

    // Do your processing with numbers[index]

    numbers[index] = "new value";

    gridAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

The `notifyDataSetChanged()` call will cause the `GridView` to update its children, and your new value will be set in the appropriate `TextView`. The `numbers` array now also has the current values, and is readily available in the `Activity` to perform the necessary checks there.